# Getting number of iterations with Microsoft Roslyn from loop condition

Tags: c#, roslyn

I have this code to parse:

```
int[] tab1 = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
for (var i = 0; i < tab1.Length - 1; i++) { };
```

How can i get the exact value of tab1.Length - 1 (4 in this example) using Microsoft Roslyn?

I can find expression tab1.Length - 1 with this code:

```
var collector = new ForCollector();
foreach (var statement in collector.ForStatements)
{
    Console.WriteLine(statement.Condition.ChildNodes().ElementAt(1));
}
```

Where ForCollector is a class inheriting SyntaxWalker with override function VisitForStatement but i don't know how to get the value of tab1.Length. I suppose i have to use SemanticModel for this purpose.

Version of Roslyn - September 2012

Comment: I don't understand. Don't you just need to write `i` in your loop?

Comment: What should it return when `tab1` is a parameter of a method? Or if it depends on user input? Or if its length is computed using `Random`?

Comment: What version of Roslyn?

Comment: My question is about value that is known during compiling phase. I quess there is a way to check whether variable is initialized or not using Roslyn and if it's initialized i want to get the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution walks the syntax tree to find what you're looking for. Notes:

1. It walks the whole tree. If you put more classes or methods in, it will only find the first. You can modify the code to find as many `for` loops as you like and then check each one.
2. I've wrapped the snippet in a method to make it easier to parse.
3. I've broken each step out for readability, you can collapse them.

Here's the source, you can dump it into a console app to run it up.

```
using System.Linq;
using Roslyn.Compilers.CSharp;

// Snip some console app wrapping

var code = @"
    public void FindI()
    {
        int[] tab1 = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
        for (var i = 0; i < tab1.Length - 1; i++) { };
    }";

        var syntaxTree = SyntaxTree.ParseText(code);

        var forStatement = syntaxTree
            .GetRoot()
            .DescendantNodes()
            .OfType<ForStatementSyntax>()
            .First();

        // Gets the name 'tab1' from the for statement condition
        var conditionMemberName = forStatement
            .DescendantNodes()
            .OfType<MemberAccessExpressionSyntax>()
            .First()
            .GetFirstToken()
            .Value;

        // Finds the first variable: int[] tab1 = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
        var member = syntaxTree
            .GetRoot()
            .DescendantNodes()
            .OfType<VariableDeclarationSyntax>()
            .First()

        // Finds the variable with the correct name 'tab1'
        var variable = member.Variables.Where(x => x.Identifier.Value == conditionMemberName).Single();

        // Find the initializer: { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
        var initializer = variable.Initializer.Value as InitializerExpressionSyntax;

        // Counds the number of items in the initializer
        var lengthOfInitializers = initializer.Expressions.Count;
```

Comment: Why don't you use `Cast()` for the for statement and the variable declaration? It would make your code shorter and more DRY.

Comment: I don't see how using `Cast()` is Writing Everything Twice (WET). It would only remove the `as` statement on the end of each parse. As for shortening the code, I mention in (3) of the post I left things in long format to make it easier to understand.

Comment: You have to first specify that you want `SyntaxKind.ForStatement` and then that it's `ForStatementSyntax`. I think that's repetition that's worth avoiding. I also don't think writing it this way makes it easier to understand.

Comment: Ah! I see. Good point, well made. I have updated the solution to use a Type search `OfType<>` rather than a `Where` search on `Syntax.Kind`. Thanks for the feedback @svick.